# Angular [ngStyle] is not taken into account

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got an issue right now using Angular [ngStyle]. Everything here seems to work except the style component that does not appear on my mat-slide-toggle component. Both tree.depth and tree.value are defined and appear correctly. I've tried multiplying tree.depth as well (as it is a relatively small number) but that has not seemed to change much. Any ideas?

```
    <div *ngFor = "let tree of m_sortingtrees" class = "sliders">
        <mat-slide-toggle [ngStyle] = "{'margin-left': tree.depth * 10}">
            {{tree.depth}}
            {{tree.value}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes if I hardcode things in css it works fine. I'm guessing this is coming from a syntax error maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're setting the `margin-left` CSS property to a non-valid value (aka with no units):

```html
<div *ngFor="let tree of m_sortingtrees" class="sliders">
    <mat-slide-toggle [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': tree.depth * 10 + 'px'}">
        {{tree.depth}}
        {{tree.value}}
    </mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```